# Google Mobile Test Error

Tags: css, viewport

When I plug in a site I'm trying to make mobile friendly into google page speed insights, it tells me the viewport isn't set and the font is too small.

It's weird because my font is set to 16px, which is what google suggests for mobile friendly sites, and I've set my viewport.

Can anyone tell me why it would be reading the page like this?

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEf7X.png

Site: gc200298785.computerstudi.es/test/
Source code: view-source:http://gc200298785.computerstudi.es/test/

Thanks!
Kayley

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked this a couple weeks ago but try adding *initial-scale=1* to your viewport meta to make it:

```
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`
```

This will change the scaling to make it larger on mobile screens (pixels are not all created equal)

Basically 16 pixels on a mobile phone is much smaller than 16 pixels on a Desktop, hope that helps a little